# Get list of available software updates on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

On OS X 10.10 and 10.11 it was possible to use the `softwareupdate` utility to fetch a list of available software updates programmatically, and in XML/PLIST format. You could write e.g.

```
softwareupdate -l -f my-updates.plist
```

and then parse the resulting PLIST-file. On macOS 10.12, this is no longer possible. The utility gives an error message instead, stating that the "-f" option is no longer available:

```
$ softwareupdate -l -f my-updates.plist
softwareupdate: invalid option -- f
usage: softwareupdate <cmd> [<args> ...]
```

Is there any way to programmatically do something that is equivalent to `softwareupdate -l -f xml-file.plist` on macOS 10.12? It doesn't have to be a command line tool, Objective-C or C or Swift-solutions are welcome as well!

(I already tried `--file`, `--xml` and similar options, but nothing seems to work. It seems like Apple just dropped this feature. I could of course just parse the output of `softwareupdate -l` with some regular expressions, but I'd prefer a less hacky solution.)